# SQL - python 3 index out of range

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, list, file

why is the list index out of range?[image: finction]

[image: query]

[image: how i am testing the function]

[image: What the file looks like]

[image: This is the error i'm getting]

Comment: Because it's not as long as you'd like it to be.

Comment: (This is actually a serious comment, how do you expect a detailed answer given the information you provided?)

Comment: Please provide your code as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 1):

There is always issues with using separated values.  For instance, if the data is missing a comma, the second index lookup on data will fail.

See simple program below that shows good and bad data.

[image]

Before referencing `data[1]`, make sure that it is not null.  You could do the same for `data[0]` if there might be a blank line in the data.

```
if data[1] is none 
    room = ""
else
    room = data[1]
```